# How to avoid exception when a dependency is missing? (WMP control)

Tags: vb.net, exception, audio, dependencies, mp3

I have an application which can play audio from URL's in MP3 format and up until now I've been using the WMP control for this task. (Interop.WMPLib.dll)

But recently I've discovered that my application will not start, throwing "System.InvalidOperationException" for clients that do not have WMP installed.

The only alternative methods I've found by searching is either using a method of which only supports WAV files or methods of which still require WMP.

Are there any alternatives which don't require much from the client?
Or is there a way to have that exception ignored if the client does not have WMP installed and just continue running the application with the mp3 playing feature disabled?

Might my implementation be causing the close on exception at startup?
Here's code that might be relevant: (I'll include how I'm handling exceptions just incase there's anything I can change in that)

.Net Framework 4.0, Target CPU: x86

Oh and 'Embed Interop Types' is 'True' for 'Interop.WMPLib.dll'

```
Imports WMPLib

Public Class frmMain
    Inherits System.Windows.Forms.Form
    Public Sub New()
        MyBase.New()
        AddHandler Application.ThreadException, AddressOf OnThreadException
        AddHandler AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException, AddressOf UnhandledExceptionEventRaised

        InitializeComponent()
        System.Windows.Forms.Application.EnableVisualStyles()
    End Sub
    Sub UnhandledExceptionEventRaised(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As UnhandledExceptionEventArgs)
        If e.IsTerminating Then
            Dim o As Object = e.ExceptionObject
            MessageBox.Show(o.ToString)
        End If
    End Sub
    Private Sub OnThreadException(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As ThreadExceptionEventArgs)
        MessageBox.Show(e.Exception.Message & Environment.NewLine & Environment.NewLine & e.Exception.InnerException.ToString)
    End Sub

    Public WithEvents mp3Player As New WindowsMediaPlayer

    'frmMain_Load etc..

    Private Sub btnAudio_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnAudio.Click
        Dim mp3URL As String = "http://host.com/file.mp3"
        mp3Player.URL = mp3URL
        mp3Player.controls.play()
    End Sub
End Class
```

Of course, there's more to the code than that but I only included anything relevant.

Help appreciated~!

Edit: I found this method http://content.gpwiki.org/index.php/VBNET:AudioVideoPlayback

Would that be more or less compatible? >-<

Answer (score 0):

Have a simple file check. On your program initialization, check if the file **Interop.WMPLib.dll** is present on the machine or not, else you don't allow the program to run

Comment: Is it necessary for it to be on the client machine if it's embedded in my application?